# How to create a tiled watermark using Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to create a tiled watermark to apply to an image using PHP Imagick.

Essentially, I'm trying to replicate the following command using Imagick instead of CLI:

```php
exec('composite -dissolve 45 -tile ' . $watermarkFilename . ' ' . $inputFilename . ' ' . $outputFilename);
```

```php
$image = new \Imagick($inputFilename);
$watermark = new \Imagick();
$watermark->newPseudoImage(
    $image->getImageHeight(),
    $image->getImageWidth(),
    "tile:$watermarkFilename"
);
$image->setImageArtifact('compose:args', '45');
$image->compositeImage($watermark, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DISSOLVE, 0, 0);
$image->writeImage($outputFilename);
```

This kind of works, except that I lose the alpha channel from the png.

I noticed that I can set a VirtualPixelMethod to TILE, but I can't figure out how to resample the watermark in order to make it tile.

```php
$watermark->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TILE);
```

Does anyone know how to create a tiling image?

Answer (score 0):

I found I can use `Imagick::textureImage()` to create a tiled version of the watermark:

```php
$image = new \Imagick($inputFilename);
$tile = new \Imagick();
$tile->newImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), 'transparent', 'png');
$watermark = $tile->textureImage(new \Imagick($watermarkFilename));
$image->setImageArtifact('compose:args', '45');
$image->compositeImage($watermark, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DISSOLVE, 0, 0);
$image->writeImage($outputFilename);
```

This solves the problem, but doesn't explain what `Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TILE` is or how it could be used to achieve the same result.